# Помогите! Редактировал CMSPluginCfg.class.php теперь сайт не работает!

Tags: php

Редактировал CMSPluginCfg.class.php
Строку public function save() {
        $fd = fopen($this->file, 'r+'); изменил на x+
Сохранил.
Обновил сайт выдает ошибку

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/1.com.ua/engine/plugins/Cfg/CMSPluginCfg.class.php on line 164

164 строка была

$str = str_replace(array('\', "'"), array('\\', "\'"), $str);
        return "'$str'";
    }

}

стала

$str = str_replace(array('\', "'"), array('\', "\'"), $str);
        return "'$str'";
    }

```
Вставил первоначальное сохраненное в блокноте содержание в файл, все равно выдает ту же ошибку
```

Comment: Символ \ надо экранировать еще одним \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

немного пошаманив, получилось что-то такое:

```
$str = str_replace(array('\\', "'"), array('\\', "\'"), $str); return "'$str'";
```

Отпишитесь заработал ли сайт

Comment: Заработало! Как отблагодарить?

Comment: @alfabet, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом). Так и отблагодарите, повысив репутацию на форуме у ответившего

Answer (score 1):

Цитата из мануала для строк в одинарных кавычках:

> Чтобы использовать одинарную кавычку
> внутри строки, проэкранируйте ее
> обратной косой чертой (\). Если
> необходимо написать саму обратную
> косую черту, продублируйте ее (\\).
> Все остальные случаи применения
> обратной косой черты будут
> интерпретированы как обычные символы:
> это означает, что если вы попытаетесь
> использовать другие управляющие
> последовательности, такие как \r или
> \n, они будут выведены как есть вместо
> какого-либо особого поведения.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало.